# react navigation getparam with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am working on an app where I navigate from a FlatList to a custom component and I need to access the data i pass to the component. The FlatList component currently looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Order from '../../components/Order/Order';
import {
    NavigationParams,
    NavigationScreenProp,
    NavigationState,
} from 'react-navigation';
  
export interface IProps {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
}

const OrdersOverview : React.FC<IProps> = props => {
    const { navigation } = props;
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.order_id}
                data={orders}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => {
                        navigation.navigate('OrderDetails', item);
                    }}>
                        <Order
                            orderNumber={item.order_id}
                            orderDate={item.orderDate}
                            dueDate={item.dueDate}
                            invoiceAmount={item.invoiceAmount}
                            status={item.state}
                            customer={item.customer}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

I am trying to pass the item I clicked to a detail screen. However I cannot access the items and I don't know why it isn't working. I am trying to access the items like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
    NavigationParams,
    NavigationScreenProp,
    NavigationState,
} from 'react-navigation';
  
export interface IProps {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;
}

const OrderDetails : React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {

    const { navigation } = props;
    const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState('information');

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{ navigation.getParam('orderDate') }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `props.route.param.orderDate`? Read the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) on how to use react navigation with typescript

Comment: @RafaelTavares I had read the documentattion before but I decided to go with a different approach. Apparently this approach does not work with TypeScript. However, the documentation does cover everything I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Typing the Params

It is possible to get full typescript support in the new version of React Navigation.  Instead of `props.navigation.getParam()` you now use `props.route.params`.

Instead of using the general type `NavigationState` as the generic on your `NavigationScreenProp`, you want to pass a type which is specific to your app and its param requirements.

I'm sure you have a type for an `Order` object already but I needed one to play with:

```
interface OrderItem {
  order_id: number;
  orderDate: string;
  dueDate: string;
  invoiceAmount: number;
  state: string;
  customer: number;
}
```

Now we say that the `OrderDetails` screen must always receive these props.

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  OrdersList: undefined;
  OrderDetails: OrderItem;
}
```

#### Warning

Be aware that it is not recommended to pass the entire order object like you are doing.  You should just pass the `order_id` and access the order itself through some sort of global state.  The docs have a [long section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#what-should-be-in-params) about it, and this is only part of it:

> It's important to understand what kind of data should be in params. Params are like options for a screen. They should only contain information to configure what's displayed in the screen. Avoid passing the full data which will be displayed on the screen itself (e.g. **pass an user id instead of user object**). Also avoid passing data which is used by multiple screens, such data should be in a global store.

> For example, say if you have a Profile screen. When navigating to it, you might be tempted to pass the user object in the params. This looks convenient, and lets you access the user objects with route.params.user without any extra work.

> However, this is an anti-pattern. Data such as user objects should be in your global store instead of the navigation state. Otherwise you have the same data duplicated in multiple places. This can leads to bugs such as the profile screen showing outdated data even if the user object has changed after navigation.

#### Accessing the Params

But I want to answer your typescript question, so I'm going to assume that you can access `orderDate` from the params even though you shouldn't.

You can import a type from the stack or tab navigator for the stack screen props, which will include `route` and `navigation`.  We set the generics to our params mapping `RootStackParamList` and the current route name `'OrderDetails'`.

```
import { StackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/stack";

type OrderDetailsProps = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'OrderDetails'>
```

Or you can define just the `route` prop with the `RouteProp` type, which takes the same generics.

```
import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";

type OrderDetailsProps = {
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'OrderDetails'>;
}
```

Either way, we get full Typescript support for the properties of `route.params`.

```
const OrderDetails : React.FC<OrderDetailsProps> = ({route}) => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Order Placed on { route.params.orderDate }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```